# Possible to auto-arrange desktop icons except for specific icons?

Tags: windows-7, desktop, desktop-icons

I like to have my desktop icons set to auto-arrange, but I would also like to have specific icons be able to break way from this rule so that I can move them off to the side where they are more visible.

Is there a way to do this in Windows 7?

Comment: Short answer: No

Comment: I concur: you cannot have your cake and eat it too.  @DavidPostill as you were first, care to answer?  If yes, ping me and I'll come back to upvote.  If not, ping me and I'll answer...

Comment: @Fabby Answer added, with possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Is there a way to do this in Windows 7?

This is not possible in Windows without installing extra software.

You could try using [Fences](https://www.stardock.com/products/fences/) from [Stardock](https://www.stardock.com/).

It has a Rules feature which allows you to define how your icons are moved. It might be possible to define a rule set that that does what you want (I haven't tried this).

> **Automatically organize your desktop shortcuts and icons with Fences®!**
>
> Key Features:
>
> - NEW! Use fences on modern, high DPI monitors.
> - Create shaded areas to organize your desktop.
> - NEW! Blur the wallpaper behind fences on Windows 10.
> - NEW! Roll up fences to the Title-bar for cleaner desktops.
> - Double click the desktop to hide or show icons.
> - **Define rules to organize your desktop icons.**
> - Swipe between multiple pages of fences.
> - Create a desktop portal from any folder.
> - NEW! Navigate the folder structure from within the fence.
> - NEW! Windows 10 compatibility.

...

> **Automatic desktop organization**
>
> Define rules for how your icons are arranged on your desktop and
>   Fences will automatically sort new icons into the fences you have
>   chosen based on your rules.

Source [Fences : Software from Stardock](https://www.stardock.com/products/fences/)

---

#### Disclaimer

I am not affiliated with [Stardock](https://www.stardock.com/) in any way, I am just an end user of their software.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll just accept the "No" part of the answer since I am too cheap to pay $10 for commodity software